# is there a way to create many input parameters?

Tags: c#, arrays, input, parameters, neural-network

```
        [Parameter("n11", DefaultValue = 0, MinValue = -1, MaxValue = 1, Step = step)]
        public double n11 { get; set; }
        [Parameter("n12", DefaultValue = 0, MinValue = -1, MaxValue = 1, Step = step)]
        public double n12 { get; set; }
        [Parameter("n13", DefaultValue = 0, MinValue = -1, MaxValue = 1, Step = step)]
        public double n13 { get; set; }
        [Parameter("n14", DefaultValue = 0, MinValue = -1, MaxValue = 1, Step = step)]
        public double n14 { get; set; }
```

I work with cAlgo for ctrader and need many input parameters like those listed above as weights for a neural network. Is there a way to generate as many input parameters as you need?

For example, when i need weights for inbetween 3 hidden layers, in which there are each 8 neurons (which would be 8x8x2 weights needed), i can just tell the programm something like "double[2,8,8]" and it creates those parameters? It would be pretty annoying when i make the neural network bigger and have to write a few thousand input parameters manually.

It would be even better it the weights could directly be stored in a 3dimensional array (between which hidden layers, from which left node, to which right node)

(It is written in c#)

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a struct out of it.

```cs
    public void MyAwesomeMethod(MyParamaterSruct s)
    {
        ...
    }

    public struct MyParameterStruct
    { 
        public double n11;
        public double n12;
        public double n13;
        public double n14;
    }
```

You can also improve performance by not copying the struct (or each value) every time you call the method:

```cs
    public void MyAwesomeMethod(in MyParamaterSruct s)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You will find that the JIT compiler will usually do that perf trick for you anyway, and that avoids you having to make your parameter mutable

Comment: What? NO!
The compiler needs to be extremely defensive about such things. You're talking about edge-cases of 100 line programs here.
On the contrary: You'd need to explicity declare your struct to be immutable by making it a readonly struct.
PS: There is nothing wrong with mutable structs. The only reason it's considered bad practice (looking at Microsoft here ;) ) is because people confuse the behavior of structs and classes. But if you can handle it, and especially need the performance, mutable structs are great.

Comment: You'll find if you examine the assembly code the JIT creates, that the JIT is eminently capable of deciding whether the struct will mutate, and whether the caller cares if it does. And readonly structs are a C# compiler thing, the JIT doesn't understand them as such